# How can I enable horizontal scrolling on Wordpress' tiny mce editor?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, scrollbar

I am building a client's site in WP and have managed to get the page / post editor
to use the same styles that are in use on the front end of the site.

My only remaining question is this - by default the editor scrolls vertically when
the content extends past the viewable window in the iframe. How can I get it to 
also scroll horizontally?

My content area is 962px wide and I want my client to be able to see the page he 
is editing in wp-admin as it would look on the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you can do that in the "writing" settings of wordpress (size of post box X lines)

Second - you have a button to make the editor full screen (so your client can use it for better preview ..

Third  - you can put this in functions.php

```
    function change_wysiwyg_height() {
    echo ‘ <style type="text/css">
    #content{ height:500px; } // put whatever
    </style>
    ‘;
    }


add_action(‘admin_head’, ‘change_wysiwyg_height’);
```

In the same function you can also do other css changes

**UPDATE I**

After reading comment -

If it will be easier for you to understand / do :

add this :

```
add_editor_style('tiny.css'); //you can change the name and / or path , as long as it correlates to the real file
```

to your functions.php

and then create a file named `tiny.css` (or whatever) in your theme directory and put this inside :

```
html .mceContentBody {
        width: 9999px; // whatever improbable size you want
}
```

Comment: What I really want to do is enable horizontal scrolling in the editor, in addition to the vertical scrolling that is already in place by default...

Comment: I understnad , and you can do that by changing the CSS properties in the code I gave . But please read the update again.